# NGINX fails to rewrite the html

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I try to set up two different services under the same NGINX in this way:

[image]

When I hit `/discovery/` from the browser, I see the result HTML page but the browser cannot load some resources that are in another directory:

[image]

So the browser request for `/eureka/css/wro.css` instead of `/discovery/eureka/css/wro.css` because, seems that NGINX does not translate properly the URLs in the HTML page.

In the source HTML, everything seems correct:

[image]

Is there any specific configuration that I miss in NGINX?

Comment: There may be other ways to do it. But when I’ve tried to do what you’re doing, I like to put everything behind the reverse proxy in the same directory structure as the reverse proxy will expose.  So if you expose /discovery/... then your app behind should be in /discovery/... your problem is probably that your location / is picking up the traffic and routing it to /eureka.  If you can change location / to be a redirect to /discovery/ and make that be the only reverse proxy... you’ll probably be happiest.  Otherwise you have to write multiple rules for each subdirectory and it gets brittle.

Comment: You are correct, I totally avoid the first option because it forces to have only a single reverse proxy. I am using your second proposal having multiple rules, one for each subdirectory.